# Boolean / PHP: why does "bool(1) > $v" result in NULL?

Tags: php, boolean

Saw this question on Toptal and got a little confused:

```
$v = 1;
$m = 2;
$l = 3;

if ($l > $m > $v) {
    echo "yes";
}
else {
    echo "no";
}
```

I get why the answer is "no", but their reasoning was a bit confusing to me:

> First, `$l > $m` will be evaluated which yields a boolean value of `1` or `true`. Comparing that boolean value to the integer value 1 (i.e., `bool(1) > $v`) will result in `NULL`, so the output will be “no”.

Why does `bool(1) > $v` become `null` and not `undefined` or `false`?

Comment: It returns a boolean, not null, https://3v4l.org/QqJe5

Comment: @Rizier123 Are you saying "bool(1) > $v" will return "false" instead of NULL? So is their reasoning on Toptal not correct?

Comment: Just because someone said something doesn't mean it's true...

Comment: @PeteKang Yes, exactly.

Comment: @Rizier123: Answer section is below

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit *Here? Right below your comment?* ;)

Comment: @Rizier123: Where my answer is

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It doesn't. [`true > 1` is `false`](https://ideone.com/jzXl2s) (because they are instead "equal").

Furthermore, [the entire program will not run](https://ideone.com/ZDakYI) because the "double conditional" is a parse error.

The answer you read is *wrong*.

This is why you shouldn't take advice from random strangers on the internet. Including me. ;)

Comment: Thank you. That's what I thought but I just wanted to double check :D!

Comment: @PeteKang See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/80646/3933332 and know that `<`/`>` does a loosely comparison.

Comment: @Rizier123: Those pipe-based ASCII tables are glorious!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I used: [this site](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html) to do it, but it seems to be broken right now, so you can use it from [the past](https://web.archive.org/web/20150413065746/http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html)

Comment: @Rizier123: Oh, so you cheated! (They have a JS error)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I wouldn't call that cheating. People who use "hidden" characters to get around the minimal character limit [for an answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285644/3933332), that is what I would call cheating :P

Comment: @Rizier123: Deleted posts obviously do not count.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit That [one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32655927/3933332) still counts. (Why was the other one deleted by a mod?)

Comment: @Rizier123: Cos it was crap, useless and late to the party. And mods hate that. :)

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record

```
<?php

$v = 1;
$m = 2;
$l = 3;

var_export( $l > $m ); // true
var_export( $m > $v ); // true
var_export( $l > ($m > $v) ); // false: (3 > true) = false
var_export( ($l > $m) > $v ); // false: (true > 1) = false
var_export( $l > $m > $v ); // parse error
```